# 'VM Exception while processing transaction: revert\n' Error Processing transaction

Tags: solidity, truffle, address.transfer, exceptions, truffle-console

I have read in various posts that this error occurs when there is a problem with executing function. So I'm asking about this error in regards to the code I have written.

Please see below:

```
contract Slot_Machine is Mortal{

  // A struct type that defines state variables of a player.
  //Every player has a wallet, amount they are willing to
  //deposit and a guess.
  struct Player{
      address payable wallet;
      uint deposit;
      uint guess;
  }

  mapping (address => Player) public player;

  constructor() public{
      newPlayer(10,5);
  }

  function sendPay(address to, uint amount) public {
      player[to].wallet.transfer(amount);// **---> where the error occurs in the truffle console**

  }
```

I've also tried simplifying the line of code, where 'to' is an address payable type:

`to.transfer(amount)`

Am I missing an exception throw or something?

Comment: Does your `Slot_Machine` contract have any ETH balance?

Comment: More specifically, does it have at least `amount` ETH balance?

Comment: No the contract itself does not have a balance. Am I calling the function from the truffle console using the accounts arrays so something like: ```instance.sendPay(accounts[1], 10, {from: accounts[0]})```

Comment: So why do you expect `x.transfer(amount)` to complete successfully then?

Comment: Because the function was being called from one account to send ether to another account, I expected the ether to move from that the calling account to the recipient. But you're basically saying that the function call will move ether from the contract balance itself to the recipient despite the call coming from a different external account? If so, then I get that. But now I'm wondering, how to send ether from one EOA to another via a contract call?

Comment: looks like my approach was wrong. I expected ether to go straight from A -> B on a contract call, when in fact it must go from (with C being the contract account): A -> C -> B.